# Extent of financial consideration before having children

Tags: halacha, money, mitzvah, children-parenting, priorities

Are there financial considerations that a couple must take before having a child or children i.e. should one have children 'at any cost' or is this not a consideration.

If yes, would these financial considerations then change if you had fulfilled your obligation of "פְּרוּ וּרְבוּ" (to the extent of whichever halachic opinion you follow)?

Answer (score 10):

[The Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/essays/71.htm) says (in a long speech about "Family Planning") that

> One of the strongest objections is fear of financial inability to support children. Naturally, parents want the best for their children, and fear of being unable to provide adequately is a powerful deterrent to having them. This is a genuine concern -- but based on an assumption which springs from a weakness of faith and presumptuousness. One who fears that he will not be able to provide is assuming that it is completely through his efforts that he does succeed. True, Torah requires that man work to provide for his family. But it is a primary tenet of Judaism that all success comes from G-d, that it is His blessings that give sustenance, not one’s own efforts alone. It is G-d Who provides for all of His creatures; another mouth will not overburden Him.
>
> An appraisal of motives might be in order. Is it possible that the concern of financial limitations may be a rationalization for living in a particular lifestyle? Contemporary society demands a standard that is, to say the least, profligate. Is it possible that we have adopted indulgences as necessities and this causes the worry about financial means? It is time to assess priorities to avoid regarding indulgence of trivial desires as necessity and a reason for not having children.

Comment: thank you for this post. What about famililes that havent 'adopted indulgences as necessities'? There are families that have many children where the father is forced to beg for money (whilst living what may be considered a 'humble' lifestyle). Being a large financial commitment (aside from other financial difficulties that could arise) is it still then considered a 'weakness in faith' to withhold from having more children?

Comment: Since when is not relying on miracles a "weakness of faith"?

Answer (score 1):

Harav Yosef Mizrahi says that since everybody person has a determined amount of money there are going to make in a lifetime. If someone has many kids than his chances of having a child that is destined to be rich is higher and he can "inherit" money to support his child who is destined to be rich from the child himself.

**If someone understands what I'm trying to explain I'd appreciate if you could reword it because I don't think I did a good job.**

Comment: Source........?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Rav Yosef Mizrahi.

Comment: Source,  as in *where* he says that.